# How to popup an external URL from a JavaScript function using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

In [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), this simple code will open a popup.

```
$.fancybox({
  'href' : '/popup/enquire.aspx?id=' + $('#productId').val()
});
```

Is there an equivalent of this in jQuery Mobile?
It supports [popups](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup/) but no example how to open an external URL dynamically like above
 (In the above using fancyBox, you don't need to write any HTML for the popup in the page that calls the popup)

I have a lot of popups from an existing website (login, enquire about a product, contact us, send to friend, etc) that I want to reuse in the mobile website.

Comment: Not without including fancyBox. And I don't know about the compatibility. I am asking because jQM already has [popups](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup/), but no example on how to open it from a function (like my code above). It has nothing to do with hover.

Comment: check this one http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/popup/methods.html you can use this functions to open and close.

Comment: @Aravinth In that example apparently the HTML has to be inline, I'm trying to call an external URL, see my sample code.

Comment: Just realised someone edited my question title, that's not what I'm asking lol, changing it back

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xbz4X/ try this and let me know if this is suitable

Comment: Hope this issue has resolved?

Comment: Thanks ScorpionRulz, the problem there is you have to define #popupLogin inline. I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically programatically open a popup (where the URL is also dynamic), just like my sample code with fancyBox, it requires no extra HTML.